# Read large number of small files efficiently in R

Tags: r

I have about 700K small files (condor logs files and less than 10 KB). There are no rules for filenames. I am using list.files to obtain all filenames, then reading them with readLines, and merge them as a list.

Currently It will take several hours to read all files. These are my codes to read log files.

```
rm(list = ls())

base <- 'logs-025'
exts <- c('log', 'out', 'err')

for (i in seq(along = exts))
{
    all_files <- list.files(base, paste0('apsim_.*.', exts[i]), full.names = TRUE)
    res <- NULL
    for (j in seq(along = all_files))
    {
        res_j <- readLines(all_files[j])
        res[[j]] <- res_j
    }
    save(res, file = paste0(Sys.info()['nodename'], '-', exts[i], '.RData'))
}
```

Is there a efficiently way to read large number of small files in R?

Thanks for any advice.

Cheers,
Bangyou

Comment: Can you clarify "efficiently"? Is the performance not good enough or is the code unclear?

Comment: Thanks @JoelKuiper. I edit my question through adding the runtime and my codes.

Comment: If your files all have the same structure (ie, all `log` files are the same, all `out` files are the same, etc), you could also concatenate them into a single file using your OS facilities. Then read the one file into R.

Comment: Yes the log files have the similar structure. Thanks @HongOoi for your advice. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the total size of the data set (i.e. will it fit in memory) you might want to memory map the files (for example with the [ff package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html))

But in general the performances of R's IO functions are poor and I can recommend writing those loops in C