# Load files from a list of file names in a data frame

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I have created a program to do a calculation from an Excel worksheet. The data for this worksheet comes from a machine. I have set the machine to export to a given folder. I want the R program to input data from this folder (data) and run the code, then export to a different folder (results). I don't want the code to run on data previously done. I currently have this done:

```
library(gdata) 
library (XLConnect)

#################### data in ########################
setwd("c:/r/data/")

datain <- list.files(pattern="*.xlsx", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

##################### results in ###################

setwd("c:/r/result/")

results <- list.files(pattern="*.xlsx", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

################## set wd back to data #################################

setwd("c:/r/c/")

torun <- datain[!(datain %in% results)]

############################################################################

dataframtorun <- data.frame(torun)

dataframtorun 
           torun
1 ./343sdasd.xlsx
2    ./4ewwq.xlsx
3  ./TRICARB.xlsx
```

I want to load the three files above and run the program in a loop.

Comment: You'll need to read the docs for `XLConnect` to determine what you want to do with each file. There's also an `xlsx` package you might consider. From there, the loop syntax in R is pretty standard, but you also have an alternative to a loop in the `lapply` function (type `?lapply` for its doc), like `list_o_dfs <- lapply(torun,function(fn) ... do stuff to read file fn ... )`

Comment: Yes but using xlconnect can you call the name from the data.frame? Like data.frame [i, 1] and then loop i so that all the files that don't have a result will be passed through the function? Sorry I am currently using my phone and don't have the code

Comment: (Sorry that I'm not familiar with the details of XLConnect's functions.) I assume XLConnect works with string file names, yeah, in which case a loop over them should be fine. You will want to assign the results to a list, like `res` in the inner loop of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084988/read-large-number-of-small-files-efficiently-in-r By the way, you can just work with `torun[i]` without making `dataframtorun` and accessing `dataframtorun[i,1]`.